# Template Parameter iteration

Tags: c++, c++11, variadic-templates

Trying to find a simpler way to iterate through a set of Variadic template parameters.

My class holds a tuple of objects represented by the Variadic template parameters. I want to perform a common operation on all the members of the tuple and return an aggregated result.

A simplified Example would be:

```
template<typename... Args>
struct Holder
{
    std::tuple<Args>    data;

    std::size_t getSize() const
    {
        return getSizeData(std::make_index_sequence<sizeof...(Args)>());
    }
    private:
       template<std::size_t... I>
       std::size_t getSizeData(std::index_sequence<I...>)
       {
           // Initialize
           std::size_t result = 0;

           // Fold expression to iterate across all members in tuple.
           ((result += std::get<I>(data).getSize()), ...);

           // Aggregated value returned.
           return result;
       }
};
```

Here the call to `getSize()` has to delegate the work `getSizeData()` to be able to perform the `fold expression` need to hit all the members of the tuple.

I have avoided using `std::get<Kind>(data).getSize()` as that would limit the tuple to storing one of each type (unless I am mistaken in someway).

Is there a simpler way of expressing this without using an extra function. ie. do all the work in `getSize()` rather than delegate the work to a `getSizeData()`?

Comment: I don't think it's possible without a helper function. Can you use c++17? Then you can do it in a single line with `std::apply`.

Comment: @cigien After hours of trying to do it before asking the question. As soon as I ask the question I find `std::apply()`. I should not have stuck C++11 in the tags. Yes I can use anything after C++11. If you answer I'll accept your answer.

Comment: Ok, is each type in `Args` supposed to have a `getSize` member function? In this code `std::get<I>(data).getSize()` I mean?

Comment: @cigien: Yes; All the `Args` support the same "Duck" type interface. This simplified example I have made that `getSize()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`std::apply`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/apply), which unpacks the tuple into a parameter pack, letting you write a fold-expression, like this:

```
std::size_t getSize() const
{
    return std::apply([](auto... a) {
        return (a.getSize() + ...);
    }, data);
}
```

Here's a [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/fsrTaj).